# How to scroll a webpage in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automatically capture the list of participants in a google meet. I am using Selenium in Python.

I logged in and joined the meeting successfully. Then while trying to get the elements and get it's text I am encountering problems.

```
names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.cSO8I.N4cbF div.G3llDe.Dxboad div.cS7aqe.NkoVdd')
```

I got a list of elements that follows:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8c985f19fd463e89e66778e6065490e7", element="227cf87e-59ec-4c2e-b880-de9bead540cb")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8c985f19fd463e89e66778e6065490e7", element="c985d1c1-1128-4d82-9864-4d8c087dd4bb")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8c985f19fd463e89e66778e6065490e7", element="d01d2f87-88eb-468b-b748-223c43e61961")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8c985f19fd463e89e66778e6065490e7", element="1d3f114e-786e-4905-a8ea-02353d0da7ef")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8c985f19fd463e89e66778e6065490e7", element="907af305-f9a9-43d1-a08a-e487c3aa18d8")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8c985f19fd463e89e66778e6065490e7", element="3cfedad6-e4cb-49ee-affa-164006bf6894")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8c985f19fd463e89e66778e6065490e7", element="8a10b259-3128-48ea-b717-9976cf2d52cd")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8c985f19fd463e89e66778e6065490e7", element="2c80a0c9-69ac-4d1a-bbf4-7e23a5bb1c4f")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8c985f19fd463e89e66778e6065490e7", element="d947ab6d-b58e-47fe-a8dd-1f8cb7bfafb7")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8c985f19fd463e89e66778e6065490e7", element="f79b2b88-a2b4-482e-ac79-ef93e0758b1d")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8c985f19fd463e89e66778e6065490e7", element="3e1d10af-a8da-415c-8fca-61139246170b")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8c985f19fd463e89e66778e6065490e7", element="845ea5b8-91b0-4a57-b161-82ff95e1bb2d")>]
```

Then, I tried extracting the names through a loop

```
for i in names:
    print(i.text)
```

It returned me some names but not all and encountered the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 2, in <module>
    print(e.text)
  File "C:\Users\GUNGUN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 76, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
  File "C:\Users\GUNGUN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\GUNGUN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\GUNGUN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.193)
```

I thought of scrolling the web page but in vain.

```
def t():
    n = int(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.eUyZxf span.rua5Nb').text.strip('(').strip(')'))
# n giving the number of participants
    L = []
    names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.cSO8I.N4cbF div.G3llDe.Dxboad div.cS7aqe.NkoVdd')
    while len(L)<n:
        try:
            for i in names:
                L.append(i.text)
        except:
            html.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    print(L)
```

It didn't scroll the web page.

And for reference I want to say that in Google Meet interfere scrolling:

[image: Scrolling in I gives no result, I need to scroll at II]

Scrolling in 1 gives no result, I need to scroll at 2.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move mouse to element first:

```py
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(By.XPATH,"xpath of right side").perform()
```

and then, you need to scroll down.

```py
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').send_keys(Keys.END)
```

You can use `Keys.PAGE_DOWN` but that will direct you to end of the participant list.

Comment: It is a good solution, but I need to work around the mouse for other works at that time, is that possible that it can be done only with keyboard?

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, actually I tried it now and it doesn't need the requirement of mouse